# Call a Css class in a nother css class

Tags: css

Hey is it posible to call a css class in an other css class.

e.g.

```
.test { font-family: verdana;}

.test2 { test ?}
```

I have a lot of keyframes. and i Need this in only one css class. is it possible?

Comment: You can do something similar with less.

Comment: Not in pure CSS. You can either make it a separate class and add it to all elements that need it or use SASS/LESS.

Comment: You would need to use a preprocessor for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to look at how to nest CSS classes.

You can't do it in normal CSS buy you can by using Sass.

With Sass you can do this:

```
.test{
  font-family: verdana;
  .test2 {
    /*CSS related only to .test2*/
  }
}
```

Comment: ah ok. an nothe question: maybe it's not possible to call a keyframe in a keyframe or?

Comment: Like this @keyframes infoseite_enable {
 animation-name: infoseite_enable1;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-name: infoseite_enable1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    
 
}

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never done any animations with CSS.